# Drawing a path of points html canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a double pendulum with canvas.
Here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/zndo9vh4/

As you guys can see a trace is drawn everytime the second part of the pendulum moves, and my way of doing that is by appending each coordinate to a "trace" array.

```
var trace = []
trace.push([x2,y2]);
```

And then I draw the trace by joining each coordinate with the last one:

```
for (let i = 1; i < trace.length; i++) {
    c.moveTo(trace[i][0], trace[i][1])
    c.lineTo(trace[i-1][0], trace[i-1][1])   
}
```

**I want to improve it.** What i've tried so far is only adding coordinates that aren't already in the array, but it's not a big improvent because the lines are drawn every loop

```
var trace = []
if(trace.includes([x2, y2]) != true){
    trace.push([x2,y2]);
}
```

The way I think could be a good improvement is by having 2 canvas (I don't know if its possible) and then draw each point but only in that canvas so I doesnt have to be redrawn. But I dont know how to implement that.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your improvement idea is great. You can indeed have two canvases!

There are two ways to go about it.

## Offscreen canvas

Using what's called an [offscreen canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas) (a canvas that is created in JavaScript but not added to the DOM), you can draw all the points onto it and then using `drawImage` (which can accept a canvas element) pass the canvas to the main context.

```
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var offscreenC = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

offscreenCanvas.width = canvas.width;
offscreenCanvas.height = canvas.height;


// in animate function, draw points onto the offscreen canvas instead
// of the regular canvas as they are added
if(trace.includes([x2, y2]) != true){
  trace.push([x2,y2]);
  var i = trace.length-1;

  if (i > 1) {
    offscreenC.strokeStyle = 'white'
    offscreenC.beginPath();
    offscreenC.moveTo(trace[i][0], trace[i][1])
    offscreenC.lineTo(trace[i-1][0], trace[i-1][1])
    offscreenC.stroke();
  }
}

c.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0);
```

## Layered Canvases

One of the downsides to the offscreen canvas approach is that you have to draw it to the main canvas every frame. You can further improve the approach by layering two canvases on top of one another, where the top one is just the pendulum and the bottom one the trace.

This way, you never have to redraw the offscreen canvas onto the main canvas, and save yourself some rendering time.

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/straker/70mj75c6/)

Comment: The rendering you think you'd win with the layering of two elements would have to be done by the *CSS* paint anyway. Might even be worse performance wise.

Comment: Thank you that worked as I wanted, I implemented more canvases https://jsfiddle.net/v7e49ubx/2/ apart from that I would like to ask how can I move the canvas position?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Move them how exactly?